# Ranking for ideal query reducing

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

I am trying to rank in the SERP's for the query "t-slot aluminum" or "t slot aluminum". I was beginning to see some progress and peaked at a position of 15.2 on August 11. Since that date, my ranking has incrementally reduced. I saw the biggest drop on August 15.

I have done nothing significant to reduce this ranking. The only thing I changed was adding/removing a Facebook pixel. Over the last three weeks the pixel is no longer in the page's file.

Does anyone see what could potentially be wrong? I have no errors in Search Console.

**Update:**

This has actually happened to several queries for my site. I was looking on SEMrush today and saw there was a Google change seven days ago. This is where the majority of my page ranks dropped.

The message shows that it has to do with page reviews. My site does not have any product/service reviews because it is not applicable.

Why would this affect me so much?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough actionable information in your question for us to assess the situation, however, we can say that there are a lot of factors associated with where a page falls within the SERPs including CTR (click through rate), CTR of other SERP links around yours, bounce backs (when a user clicks the back arrow to return to the SERPs), the general semantic (topical) strength of the content, links to the content, citations, how many clicks from the home page to reach the content, whether content is added on a regular basis (does not have to be often), and so on.

Also consider when and how people search for your content. All queries for a subject cycles between busier times and not so busy times. For example, in real estate, people look to move at different times. People look to move before school starts, before the holidays, when jobs open up in an area, etc. During these less busy times, a link in the SERPs may drop a bit but return to higher positions during busy times. I can gauge when people are ready to move by activity found in Search Console.

There are too many factors that play into your question. The only thing you can do is to make sure your content is high quality, your site encourages users to stay on your site longer, that you have quality links to your content and site, and that your content and site is engaging. Do these things right and once you are satisfied with your content and site, leave it alone except to post new content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After doing more research, I believe I found correlation. See my question update. Any ideas?

Comment: @Paul It looks like you nailed it! I forgot about the update. I have not researched the most recent updates, however, when it comes to reviews, things have changed and what that means to webmasters, is up in the air. I am in and out all day today. If I can research this more later, I certainly will. Cheers!!